# Animation of an array with matplotlib library

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot

I want to animate my array as a scatter plot, this is the shape of my data:

```
 data = np.array([[[[1], [2], [7], [1]],
                 [[2], [4], [9], [1]]],
                 [[[5], [2], [8], [1]],
                  [[3], [4], [9], [1]]]])
```

my data is long and this is a short example to explain what I want to achieve:

I want to animate my array in a way that in the first frame shows the first array which the first row is x and the second row is y, so one point would be (1,2) and the other (2,4), in the second frame shows the points for second array which is (5,2) and (3,4).

I have already try this:

```
num_frames = data.shape[0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(data[0,:, 0, 0], data[0,:, 1, 0])  # Set initial offsets to empty

def update(i):

    scat.set_offsets(np.c_[data[i,:,0,0], data[i,:,1,0]])

    return scat



 animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(data), interval=1000,repeat=False)


 plt.show()
```

It only shows the first frame, how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Why is your data formatted like that?

Comment: It shows two frames since `len(data) == 2`. But I don't understand why your data is formatted like so I cannot say if that is what you intended.

Comment: For some reason I should work with this format.

Comment: You say that based on what?